# Linux box as network gateway changes source address

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ipsec

I have a Ubuntu Server box(A) with an IPSec tunnel to another datacenter(AWS, through a VPC VPN). The tunnel is fine and I can ping the other side of the tunnel.

The problem is when I try to communicate with any host on the other side of the tunnel.

Suppose I have the following config:

**Box A:** 172.31.0.5

**Box B:** 172.30.0.5

If I do the following:

```
A> ping 172.30.0.5
```

The ICMP packets arrive in the target server(B), but their source address is not the IP of the source server(A).

Instead, they arrive with 169.254.248.xxx as the source address which is the private address of the IPSec tunnel within AWS VPC.

As 169.254.248.xxx does not exist outside box A, box B can't send a reply and the packets are lost.

I certain that this is a problem with my routing setup on server A, how can I debug this to find a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "169.254.248.xxx does not exist outside box A"?  You said that 169.254.248.xxx is the address range of the IPSec tunnel, so that address existing in the tunnel.  Box A has multiple IPs, `172.31.0.5` and `169.254.248.xxx`.  The networking stack is picking the best address to get to `172.30.0.5`, which is the VPN IP.

Comment: The counterpart in AWS for 169.254.248.xxx is not on the box B, but in AWS infrastructure. The IPSec tunnel is not between A and B but between A and B's network router.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the interface `ping` should use to send packets.

On Windows:

```
ping -S 172.31.0.5 172.30.0.5
```

On Linux:

```
ping -I 172.31.0.5 172.30.0.5
```

Comment: Tried this. No reply in the ping command. I got the following on tcpdump: https://gist.github.com/greenboxal/7e7dea68037c736e1907

Comment: @greenboxal, and what's wrong?  Isn't the 3rd line on "Box A" the ping reply coming back??

Comment: The ping command doesn't receives the reply. This is the log:
https://gist.github.com/greenboxal/71fe53cf134ea52465e0

Comment: @greenboxal, do you know what the IP `172.30.10.214` is?

Comment: Sorry, this IP is 172.30.0.5, I've just changed on the question to a simple one.

Comment: Hmm, everything in the dumps looks right.